# jquery rule for href with # only

Tags: jquery, href

How to apply a rule on a class .button that have a href of "#" only

in fact, any button with a real href will do his button thing, the other one, onother thing

just to clear thing

```
$(".jbutton").click( function () {
```

i like that function to be executed on anything BUT #...
exclude #

is it more clear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Live Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/nEdHH/

**HTML**

```
<button href="#" id="button0"></button>
<button href="123" id="button1"></button>
<button href="123" id="button2"></button>
```

**JS**

```
$('button[href!="#"]').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: [`button`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) element does not have `href`attribute, it would be correct to use `a` element in your example

Answer (score 1):

You should use [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

```
$('a[href!="#"].button').click(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".jbutton[href='#']").click(...
```